# How to set email policies in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to directly configure an email account to the default android mail application. I have the details of the account for particular user.The details are such as username, password,IMAP server,port.I am developing an application that creates policies to configure mailbox directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for now in android..

Comment: Wise guy, if it is not possible then how [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en) works?

Comment: i wanted then application to set default android mail policy not for my own mail application.

Comment: you can mention explicitly in your receiving app which will open a dialog box from whatever app trying to send/use mail. Kinda like when you have both gmail and yahoomail app installed, it opens a dialog to choose from and the user can set it as default too